# rotate image in android imageview

Tags: android, image, rotation

I want to build an application where, I have an image displayed via (ImageView).
and a textbox in the application.
I want to rotate the image in continuously for about 10 degree for every one second. when the image rotates, the textbox should display the number of times the image is rotated. 
I tried rotating the image but every time the application crashes or doesn't show up in the screen.

Can someone help me with the code plz ??

Thanks

Comment: Refer this site, http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/05/bitmap-operations-like-re-sizing.html

Answer (score 2):

Create animation inn res/anim with this code

```
<rotate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:duration="36000" />
```

and in your Activity:

```
Animation rotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate);
findViewById(R.id.yourImageId).startAnimation(rotate);
rotate.reset();
rotate.start();
```

Comment: should i create a xml file in res/anim to paste that <rotate..> code ? or is it ok if i paste it in main.xml ?

Comment: you must create the file totate.xml in res/anim

Comment: couldn't make it work.. program crashes when run though it doesn't give any build errors.. have created main.xml file with imageview (with android:src), text and button. and added ur code in "onCreate" block in .java.. but :( .. if you dont mind can you plz explain in detail ?

Comment: was it crashed or nothing happens? try to set duration to 1000

Comment: changed the duration.. but still the same thing. crashes !!

Comment: can you post your main xml and aour onCreate methiod from Activity?

Comment: thanks ice it worked... I had a copy of rotate.xml code in the main.xml.. is there any way to rotate the image for specific angle in clockwise or anticlockwise direction ? now it just rotates in clockwise directions continuously.

Comment: try to change the values "fromDegree" and "toDegree"

Comment: though it changes if we change the "fromdegree" and "todegree" but it doesn't stops there it then again resets to its original position. i want it to stop there itself(till to degree)